# How to deal with a potentially dangerous Request.Path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).

I am trying to pass a DateTime and an int to an ActionResult, I have created a custom route to deal with it. I can't see (:) in my URL so don't know how to replace the string. Is it the (%) in the date of my URL that are causing it? Here is my code that is passing the variables to the controller:

```
//View
DateTime raceDate = DateTime.Today;
<center><a href="@Url.Action("EventInfo", new {raceDate= date, trackID=trID})" class="buttonize" target="_blank">View</a></center>

//Controller
public ActionResult EventInfo(DateTime raceDate, int trackID )
    {
        EventInfomodel = new EventInfo();
        model.MyRace = db.GetRaceDetails(raceDate, trackID)
        return View(model);
    }

//Route.Config
routes.MapRoute("Home/EventInfo", "Home/EventInfo/{raceDate}/{trackID}", new { controller = "Home", action = "EventInfo", raceDate = UrlParameter.Optional, trackID= UrlParameter.Optional });
```

The URL in my browser looks like this:

```
 Home/EventInfo/04/22/2019%2000%3a00%3a00/59
```

I'm completely new MVC and C# so any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: You have two parameters, Home/EventInfo/{raceDate}/{trackID} race date and track id. The url in your browser is : Home/EventInfo/04/22/2019%2000%3a00%3a00/59
Your raceDate is being passes as 04/22/2019, in which the / is considered in the path which wont be existing. Try formatting your date and then try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Praneet Nadkar
Your suggestion has worked, I formatted the date to a string in my view like so:

```
DateTime mydate = DateTime.Today;
string   date   = mydate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Now my URL looks much better and works

```
Home/EventInfo/2019-04-22/59
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Security is reason because of that you getting error

Why : URL encoding ensures that all browsers will correctly transmit text in URL strings. Characters such as a question mark (?), ampersand (&), slash mark (/), and spaces might be truncated or corrupted by some browsers.

Solution : 
 When you compose your URL need to be encoded in format .

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(<Your URL>);
```

Thank You.

Comment: And Also your Date format Contains "/" characters , so that the MVC routing use
"/" character to define route in URL ..Home/EventInfo/04/22/2019 ....not such path exists in your route table